# Creating a matrix with sequential numbers and combination

Tags: python, matrix

how can i create a matrix with such running number as followed?

```
[0,0,0,0]
[1,0,0,0]
[2,0,0,0]
...
[9,0,0,0]
[10,0,0,0]
[0,1,0,0]
[1,1,0,0]
[2,1,0,0]
...
[9,1,0,0]
[10,1,0,0]
```

the goal is to reach [10,10,10,10]. please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
[[l, k, j, i] for i in range(11) for j in range(11) for k in range(11) for l in range(11)]
```